# How to see compiler invocation in colcon build

Tags: ros, ros2, colcon

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I build a package with `colcon build` and get an error about including a missing header file. I suspect something is off with the `-I` flags passed to the compiler. How can I see the exact command with which the compiler is called?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/363112/how-to-see-compiler-invocation-in-colcon-build/) by [fredBeauj](https://answers.ros.org/users/59109/fredbeauj/) on ROS Answers with karma: 131 on 2020-10-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 1):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Assuming you are referring to a CMake packages using Make under the hood: you can prefix the `colcon build` invocation with `VERBOSE=1`  optionally together with `--event-handlers console_direct+`to see `stdout` output directly rather than having to look in the log files (`log/latest/<pkgname>/stout.log`).

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2020-10-09

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's in the [colcon manual](https://colcon.readthedocs.io/en/released/user/how-to.html) but it wasn't clear enough so I missed it the first time

```
colcon build --packages-select my_pkg --event-handlers console_direct+
```

As an alternative, it the package has already been built and `cmake` uses `make`, one can just go to the build directory and invoke `make` directly

```
cd build/my_pkg
make
```

When there is a lot of errors, it's useful to step through the colored output of the compiler

```
unbuffer colcon build --packages-select mpc_follower --event-handlers console_direct+ |& less -r
```

the `unbuffer` command is available via `sudo apt install expect`

---

Originally posted by [fredBeauj](https://answers.ros.org/users/59109/fredbeauj/) with karma: 131 on 2020-10-09

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2